# Event Listening for Key Combination not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events

I am trying to implement several hotkeys into an application.
I want to have key combination from alt+1 till alt+9.

The alt+1 combination is working like a charm (breakpoint reached), but alt+2 is not working (breakpoint not reached).

Can someone explain that?

```
@HostListener('document:keydown.alt.1', ['$event'])
  doThis(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    // action();
    e.preventDefault();
  }

@HostListener('document:keydown.alt.2', ['$event'])
  doThat(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    // action();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
```

Comment: I just tried in your code by just putting a console log and I see it firing just fine, can you make a stackblitz that has the error? One thing to note is that make sure when you are doing the key combos you are actually focused in the actual page itself and not else where. For instance if I try the key combo after clicking in the console it won't fire the alt key

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't reproduce it either. Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m8phzk?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: okay, my solution did work after i started the application in a new browser window. maybe its because im extending a directive where all the hotkeys are collected...

Answer (score 1):

So I am not able to reproduce the issue, couple of things to note:

- Make sure you are actually focused on the page itself
- check your console for any JS errors as that will stop most things from continuing to execute as expected.
- As another option you can also try listening to the key events like so:

  ```
  @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(e) {
    if (e.altKey && e.key == 1) {
      console.log('alt and 1');
    } else if (e.altKey && e.key == 2) {
      console.log('alt and 2');
    }
  }
  ```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uc7ssc?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Where you have one HostListener for the keydown event and we are filtering for the actions that we want.

---

**Edit 2:** I've made an updated stackblitz showing a possible way to handle multiple key strokes (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7lrjat?file=src/app/app.component.ts). The big picture idea here is that we create a `Stack` a simple data structure that follows the FILO principle (First in Last Out, think of stacking plates. The first plate is the last one you can access) and we create a timeout function to let the user have a chance to quickly input their keys before we execute the code.

You could also avoid that timeout, if you'd like, and modify the code a bit by checking to make sure that the second key is a number or not. By the way, that is what the built in method `isFinite` does. Now in TypeScript they haven't set it up to where it can accept a string as an input, thus the preceding + in order to cast the string value of `lastKey.key`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This is also working. great, thank you, i am choosing this over my solution, its more elegant i think :)

Comment: Than you, if it is working for you feel free to also mark it as the chosen answer to help others in the future. One thing to make sure is that it is not going to override default behavior for other keys so make sure to test/account for that

Comment: I want to even extend this feature to key combinations like alt + shift + number, but something like e.altKey && e.shiftKey && e.key == 1  is not working

Comment: Although, btw, the reason your above code didn't work is that while you're holding down  shift, and you're clicking 1 (Assuming it is 1 where its alternate is !) it would then actually be altKey, shiftKey and "!"

Answer (score 1):

To add for my specific use case, needing a keycombo with Alt that works on Mac and Windows:

```
@HostListener("window:keydown", ["$event"])
  public onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.altKey && event.code === "KeyL") { // using .code, as .key value can change depending if alt/shift/ctrl/cmd are pressed
      // do your thing
    }
  }
```

My preferred approach, listening for `document:keydown.alt.l` didn't work, I suspect because Alt + L on a Mac keyboard creates a special character `¬` that is not recognised by the HostListener

Answer (score 0):

`event.preventDefault();`, probably, should go before custom behavior, not after